# Unable to download database as CSV

Tags: php, mysql, database, select-into-outfile

Im trying to download a whole database but i keep getting the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' LINES TERMINATED BY ''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\cookies\download_db.php
>   on line 6

My code:

```
<?php 
    require 'db_key.php';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ventas INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/db_downlaod.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or exit(mysqli_error($conn));

    mysqli_close($conn);

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=db_downlaod.csv');
    readfile('/tmp/db_downlaod.csv');
    unlink('/tmp/db_downlaod.csv');
    exit();
?>
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you're querying twice here. You also have a quotes concatenation issue

Comment: Escape the quote, and double escape the new line

Comment: Thanks to both, i assumed it was a quotation error but even tho i can understand what your suggesting without an example i wont be able to apply it.

Comment: Welcome @Minnen Since you're inside a double quoted query, your `ENCLOSED BY '"'` should be `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` and escaping the double quote.

Comment: also double check your file name. It might be `db_downlaod` but that is actually spelled `db_download`, just saying.

Comment: you'll also be getting another error when you fix it and it will contain "near 1" when you do run this.

Comment: I should have put what I posted in comments in an answer instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner There still would have been the issue with the new lines.

Comment: @user3783243 Oh I see. Well that part eluded me. I guess I'll just leave well enough alone here and they can use some of my comments to fix this and deal with that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the PHP SQL string at the `enclosed by` bit then start a new string at the next single quote. You also need to double escape the new line since you are in double quotes and want mysql to get it as `\n`. Try:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ventas INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/db_downlaod.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
```

Visual:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ventas INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/db_downlaod.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
                                                                                                                                 closes PHP>^^<starts a new single quoted PHP string
```

You also are making 2 queries, the second of which is to a variable that is unassigned, `$sql`.

Remove:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or exit(mysqli_error($conn));
```

and or possible add that error reporting to the first function call/query execution.